# Check if image exist in Cache Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I want to check if image url is contained inside cache. I am using `Picasso` image loader .

this is my code

```
new Picasso.Builder(this).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client)).build();
```

now `Picasso.getCache()`  does not have `get(key)` .

though  `Cache` class internally uses LRUDiskCache but its `private`

Any ideas??

Comment: I cannot find a way to get a boolean, but you can use `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` to display an icon on your images. That lets you visually see what images are cached (and in memory or on disk).

Comment: fork the repo and add the method to expose the cache yourself?

Comment: are you talking of part of your program or just about android unit test case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jake already answered this on Twitter (https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/679403330809028608), but I'm reposting the answer here for visibility.

> You could make a request with a network policy of `OFFLINE` and if it fails then the image is not in the disk cache.

Comment: I am the one who asked him :)